# Was there an idiom meaning the same as English idiom "Must be a day ending in 'y'!" or Croatian "Ista priča svakog dana!"?

Tags: idiom

Croatian "Ista priča svakog dana!" literally translates as "Eadem fabula cuiusque diei!".

Comment: Can you explain what you want the idiom to mean? I've never heard that English one.

Comment: Used as an adjective, *quisque* means "whichever", not "each". *Quisque* only means "each one" when it's a substantive.

Comment: The Croatian just means "same story every day." The English is a pretty uncommon idiom. Are you looking to translate the meaning (as in the Croatian) or find an analogous idiom? Honestly I'd just translate the Croatian part into English--I'm not sure what it adds beyond a literal translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious quotable that comes to mind in this spirit is:

> Nihil sub sole novum

Though this isn't a Classical idiom, of course, but a quote from the Vulgate ([Ecclesiastes 1:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes%201&version=VULGATE) there, 1:9 everywhere else, including [in the original now](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/ecclesiastes/1-9.htm)). A common variant is *Nihil novi sub sole*, with a partitive genitive and a different word order.